# MongoDB user lost

Tags: mongodb

We have a Mongo Database for testing purposes on a cloud server.
Recently, this server almost run out of space (97% disk used), and that resulted in Mongo writes failing. I decided to resize the server to have more free space.

Important detailed that i set the auth parameter in the config to true, so each clients had to auth before using the db. I thought this is normal. I created a user with the following command, which worked:

```
db.addUser( { user: "username",pwd: "password",roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } );
```

Now, what happened, that when the resize happened and mongo restarted, i cannot get any reads  / writes to the database, only if i set the auth = false parameter in the config. I couldn't even add a user from localhost.
The other interesting thing was that i switched off auth and recreated the same user - it succeeeded, which means the user got lost!

Ok, i have lost the user after a restart. That's bad. What's worse that still, i can't get this user to auth from the remote clients.
I have no idea why is this happening, what went wrong. 
The data, which is originally intended to create still exists, count() returns 111090914, which about what is expected. I can also do find(), so that data is OK.

Comment: You have 111 million users in ``db.system.users``? ``system.*`` should be reserved for internal use. Not sure if this is part of your problem, but it definitely is an unusual usage.

Comment: how did you verify the original addUser worked?  were you authenticating and using that user for a while before the disk filled up, etc?

Comment: I have 111 million rows in the data table i was filling up.

I verified addUser was working, because i used to auth from remote clients using that. This clients failde to auth since the restart.

Comment: had the same problem recently two time , as soon as I restart the mongo instance. Users records are lost